# Outer join of two data frames that repeats for all customers (python)

Tags: python, join, outer-join

How can I do an outer join for each customer?

I have a dataset like this

```
 Customer      Timestamp        Other_Col
     A    2017-05-01 00:01:00     Jun
     A    2017-05-01 00:02:00     Sep
     A    2017-05-01 00:03:00     Jun
     B    2017-05-07 23:58:00     Sep
     B    2017-05-07 23:59:00     Sep
```

And another like this

```
         Timestamp
     2017-05-01 00:01:00
     2017-05-01 00:02:00
     2017-05-01 00:03:00
     2017-05-07 23:58:00
     2017-05-07 23:59:00
```

I want to get all the timestamstamps for every customer in my dataframe as such

```
 Customer      Timestamp        Other_Col
     A    2017-05-01 00:01:00     Jun
     A    2017-05-01 00:02:00     Sep
     A    2017-05-01 00:03:00     Jun
     A    2017-05-07 23:58:00     NaN
     A    2017-05-07 23:59:00     NaN
     B    2017-05-01 00:01:00     NaN
     B    2017-05-01 00:02:00     NaN
     B    2017-05-01 00:03:00     NaN
     B    2017-05-07 23:58:00     Sep
     B    2017-05-07 23:59:00     Sep
```

How can I do this? Doing a merge(how= 'outer') does not do the trick but I can't make it depend on the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do left join to a "base" table to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.txt',sep=';')
df1
Customer    Timestamp   Other_Col
0   A   2017-05-01 00:01:00 Jun
1   A   2017-05-01 00:02:00 Sep
2   A   2017-05-01 00:03:00 Jun
3   B   2017-05-07 23:58:00 Sep
4   B   2017-05-07 23:59:00 Sep

df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.txt',sep=';')
df2
Timestamp
0   2017-05-01 00:01:00
1   2017-05-01 00:02:00
2   2017-05-01 00:03:00
3   2017-05-07 23:58:00
4   2017-05-07 23:59:00


base = pd.DataFrame()
base['Customer']  = ['A']*5 + ['B']*5 
base['Timestamp'] = list(df2['Timestamp'])*2


pd.merge(base,df1,how='left',on=['Customer','Timestamp'])
Customer    Timestamp   Other_Col
0   A   2017-05-01 00:01:00 Jun
1   A   2017-05-01 00:02:00 Sep
2   A   2017-05-01 00:03:00 Jun
3   A   2017-05-07 23:58:00 NaN
4   A   2017-05-07 23:59:00 NaN
5   B   2017-05-01 00:01:00 NaN
6   B   2017-05-01 00:02:00 NaN
7   B   2017-05-01 00:03:00 NaN
8   B   2017-05-07 23:58:00 Sep
9   B   2017-05-07 23:59:00 Sep
```